# TypeError when make migration with django and cassandra

Tags: python, django, cassandra

When I execute `python manage.py migrate` I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: Unknown option(s) for sync_cassandra command: app_label, fake, fake_initial, interactive, migration_name, run_syncdb. Valid options are: database, help, no_color, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, verbosity, version.
```

I'm using Cassandra 3.11.2, Python 3.5.2 and django 2.0.7. All run in Ubuntu Server 16.04

**Edit to add settings.py**

https://pastebin.com/s4fQCNEk

I think everything is fine in settings file... I was triying to reinstall cassandra, cassandra_engine and doesn't works.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your settings.py

Comment: @c.grey this is my settings.py https://pastebin.com/s4fQCNEk

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your python code, otherwise it's hard to say for sure.

It could be that you are missing the relevant module `import`: 
https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/django-cassandra-engine-1.1.0/autoapi/management/commands/sync_cassandra/index.html

You can take a look here, I think you will find this useful:
https://github.com/r4fek/django-cassandra-engine/blob/master/django_cassandra_engine/management/commands/sync_cassandra.py

Comment: in the following pastebin you can see the python code: https://pastebin.com/h60AfVd9

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the question posted here: [Django migration raised TypeError: Unknown option(s) for sync_cassandra command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059483/django-migration-raised-typeerror-unknown-options-for-sync-cassandra-command/54726812)

I believe that this is the result of [a change in Django as of version 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#call-command-validates-the-options-it-receives), where the `call_command()` function was updated to validate options passed to it. If the option can't be validated (i.e., does not appear in the code of whatever module you're drawing on), then you get this TypeError.

Search your code base for instances of `call_command()` that use any of the unknowns options that are listed in the TypeError message you received. Depending on their purpose, you could consider two options:

1. Remove the unknown option from the `call_command()`
2. Add an appropriate `parser.add_argument()` function in the file containing the `call_command()` with unknown options. Example from the Django documentation shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).