# Django migration raised TypeError: Unknown option(s) for sync_cassandra command

Tags: django, cassandra, django-rest-framework, cqlengine

I trying to use Cassandra database for my Django rest application. When I am using SQLite database the migration working fine. However, when I am changing the database to use cassandra I am getting the following error.

```
 TypeError: Unknown option(s) for sync_cassandra command: 
 app_label, fake, fake_initial, interactive, migration_name, run_syncdb. 
 Valid options are database, help, no_color, pythonpath, settings, skip_checks, stderr, stdout, traceback, verbosity, version.
```

I am running cassandra service in another shell. Also I have created a Keyspace named project_db using cqlsh.

The setting.py file is given below. I am getting the same error even I am changing my database to cassandra only i.e. removing the SQLite database.

```
    """
    Django settings for project project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.4.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'm8m_d3=qx)&fq1j2xlz&b$(!=82#w3kljq(68n9-@%x*1=e70m'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django_cassandra_engine',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'src.user',
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

    from cassandra import ConsistencyLevel

    DATABASES = {
        'sqlite': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        },
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
            'NAME': 'project_db',
            'USER': 'user',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
            'TEST_NAME': 'test_db',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'replication': {
                    'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                    'replication_factor': 1
                },
                'connection': {
                    'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE,
                    'retry_connect': True
                    # + All connection options for cassandra.cluster.Cluster()
                },
                'session': {
                    'default_timeout': 10,
                    'default_fetch_size': 10000
                    # + All options for cassandra.cluster.Session()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]

    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True

    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this is the result of [a change in Django as of version 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#call-command-validates-the-options-it-receives), where the `call_command()` function was updated to validate options passed to it. If the option can't be validated (i.e., does not appear in the code of whatever module you're drawing on), then you get this TypeError.

Search your code base for instances of `call_command()` that use any of the unknowns options that are listed in the TypeError message you received. Depending on their purpose, you could consider two options:

1. Remove the unknown option from the `call_command()`
2. Add an appropriate `parser.add_argument()` function in the file containing the `call_command()` with unknown options. Example from the Django documentation shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! `stealth_options = ('option_name', ...)` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

See this for Consistency level at :

[datastax documentation / consistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html)

:: Use consistency with no options, to show the current consistency level:

Example: 
~$ CONSISTENCY

> Current consistency level is ONE.

**Note:** Before go to level one, you can edit your code to:

```
'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.SERIAL,
```

To check validation of other parameters!

---